# passing 2 variables into passedView

Tags: java, string

I can't seem to get this. I'm trying to pass two strings to a new activity but can only get one to pass. Can someone help? I would like the passed strings to say "I would like" movieName movieGroup "everyday"

```
public class Main22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
String passedVar=null;
private TextView passedView= null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    passedVar=getIntent ().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA + "movieName");
    passedVar2=getIntent ().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA + "movieGroup");
    passedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    passedView.setText("I would like  " + passedVar, passedVar2 + "everyday");


}
```

Comment: `TextView` doesn't have any `setText(...)` method which accepts 2 `String`s. Also you don't seems to use the correct variable names and some of the variables may not have been defined.

Comment: The variable are both defined in MainActivity. If I remove passedVar2 this works. Im trying to add movieGroup

Comment: Try this: `passedView.setText("I would like  " + passedVar +", "+ passedVar2 + "everyday");`

Comment: passedVar2 is in red and says "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: That is because it was never defined. Try to define it like this: `String passedVar=null, passedVar2 = null;`

Comment: you are awesome! it worked thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
   String passedVar=null;
   String passedVar2=null;
   private TextView passedView= null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  passedVar=getIntent ().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA +"movieName");
  passedVar2=getIntent ().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA + "movieGroup");
  passedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  passedView.setText("I would like " + passedVar + "," + passedVar2 + "everyday");
}
```

Notice change in

```
passedVar + "," + passedVar2
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not received favourably on this site.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for advice on how to answer questions.